# Magento 1.8 - This shipping method is currently unavailable

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, usps

I have issues with my USPS method in checkout, I have this error:

**This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.**

I apply the SUPEE-10336 patch too is the same, then I turn on the debug in the extension and there I have something like this:

```
2017-10-05T19:50:26+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IntlRateV2Request USERID="662THEAF7311"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="0"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><Country>Canada</Country><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width/><Length/><Height/><Girth/></Package></IntlRateV2Request>

    [result] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Areas Served: All</ExpressMail><AreasServed>Please reference Express Mail for Areas Served.</AreasServed><AdditionalRestrictions>No Additional Restrictions Data found.</AdditionalRestrictions><Service ID="12"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>62.00</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>106</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>1 - 3 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>USPS GXG&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Envelopes</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced regular size cardboard envelope (12-1/2" x 9-1/2"), the legal-sized cardboard envelope (15" x 9-1/2") and the GXG Tyvek envelope (15-1/2" x 12-1/2")</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>70</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="1"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>40.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>107</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>3 - 5 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail Express International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt;</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>Max. length 42", max. length plus girth combined 79"</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>66</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="10"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>41.50</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>107</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>3 - 5 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail Express International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Flat Rate Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Envelope: 12-1/2" x 9-1/2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="17"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>41.50</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>107</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>3 - 5 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail Express International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Legal Flat Rate Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Envelope: 15" x 9-1/2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="27"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>41.50</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>107</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>3 - 5 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail Express International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Padded Flat Rate Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Envelope: 12-1/2" x 9-1/2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="11"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>59.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Large Flat Rate Box</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Box: 23-11/16" x 11-3/4" x 3" or 12" x 12" x 5-1/2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 20 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>20</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="9"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>45.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Medium Flat Rate Box</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Box: 13-5/8" x 11-7/8" x 3-3/8" or 11" x 8-1/2" x 5-1/2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 20 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>20</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="16"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>24.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Small Flat Rate Box</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Box: 8-5/8" x 5-3/8" x 1-5/8"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="24"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>24.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; DVD Flat Rate priced box</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Box: 7-9/16" x 5-7/16" x 5/8"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="25"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>24.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Large Video Flat Rate priced box</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Box: 9-1/4" x 6-1/4" x 2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="8"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>23.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Flat Rate Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Envelope: 12-1/2" x 9-1/2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="22"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>23.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Legal Flat Rate Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Envelope: 15" x 9-1/2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="23"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>23.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Padded Flat Rate Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Envelope: 12-1/2" x 9-1/2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="18"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>23.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Gift Card Flat Rate Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Envelope: 10" x 7"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="20"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>23.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Small Flat Rate Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Envelope: 10" x 6"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="19"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>23.95</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>108</ServiceID><ServiceName>Insurance</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price><DeclaredValueRequired>True</DeclaredValueRequired></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><SvcCommitments>6 - 10 business days to many major markets</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>Priority Mail International&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; Window Flat Rate Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>USPS-Produced Envelope: 10" x 5" or 12-1/2" x 9-1/2"&lt;br>Maximum weight 4 pounds.</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="13"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>1.61</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>100</ServiceID><ServiceName>Certificate of Mailing</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>1.35</Price></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>103</ServiceID><ServiceName>Registered Mail</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>14.95</Price></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><InsComment>SERVICE</InsComment><SvcCommitments>Varies by destination</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>First-Class Mail&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; International Letter</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>Max. length 11-1/2", height 6-1/8" or thickness 1/4"</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>.22</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="14"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>2.71</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>100</ServiceID><ServiceName>Certificate of Mailing</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>1.35</Price></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>103</ServiceID><ServiceName>Registered Mail</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>14.95</Price></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><InsComment>SERVICE</InsComment><SvcCommitments>Varies by destination</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>First-Class Mail&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#174;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt; International Large Envelope</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>Max. length 15", height 12" or thickness 3/4"</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="15"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>9.50</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID>109</ServiceID><ServiceName>Electronic USPS Delivery Confirmation&#8482; International (E-USPS DELCON INTL&#8482;)</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>0.00</Price></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>100</ServiceID><ServiceName>Certificate of Mailing</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>1.35</Price></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>103</ServiceID><ServiceName>Registered Mail</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>14.95</Price></ExtraService><ExtraService><ServiceID>105</ServiceID><ServiceName>Return Receipt</ServiceName><Available>True</Available><Price>3.85</Price></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ValueOfContents>6.95</ValueOfContents><InsComment>SERVICE</InsComment><SvcCommitments>Varies by destination</SvcCommitments><SvcDescription>First-Class Package International Service&amp;lt;sup&amp;gt;&amp;#8482;&amp;lt;/sup&amp;gt;</SvcDescription><MaxDimensions>Other than rolls: Max. length 24", max length, height and depth (thickness) combined 36"&lt;br>Rolls: Max. length 36". Max length and twice the diameter combined 42"</MaxDimensions><MaxWeight>4</MaxWeight></Service><Service ID="2"><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>2.8</Ounces><MailType>All</MailType><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Width>0.0</Width><Length>0.0</Length><Height>0.0</Height><Girth>0.0</Girth><Country>CANADA</Country><Postage>0.00</Postage><ExtraServices><ExtraService><ServiceID/><ServiceName/><Available>False</Available><Price/></ExtraService></ExtraServices><ServiceErrors><ServiceError><Id>50050</Id><Description>The Origin ZIP Code and the Destination Postal Code is required for ECOMPRO when mailing to Canada.</Description></ServiceError></ServiceErrors></Service></Package></IntlRateV2Response>
    [__pid] => 17026
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the very common error that causes a site to not be able to retrieve USPS shipping rates. we found the source of the bug:

If the ZIP/Postal Code is using a US zip code, it can only be the five digit ZIP Code. If you use the ZIP+4 that the Post Office actually loves, this will confuse USPS servers and will return an error message.

You can set this in the Shipping Settings section in the Magento Admin area.

System –> Configuration –> Shipping Settings

[Please check the zip code field in the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdVMn.png)

This is how you can correct it:

[Please try using just the Zip code of 5 digits and it must work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy9S7.png)

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer, I see this error only when I choose Canada as customert location, so if the customer are from canada will see this message, if the customer is from USA everything will be fine, I try with ZIP+4 digits and with zip code with 5 digits is the same, you have any idea why?

Comment: Can you please confirm that in the USPS shipping method settings, Have you added Canada in the Allowed countries?

Comment: How I can add Canada in the Allowed countries?